# Automapper ignore object mapping based on condition

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

My problem could be schematized like this :
I have a domain class represented like this

```
public class DomainClass {

  public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
  public int Type {get;set}
}
```

And I have two distincts tables in database that matches different type :

```
public class TypeClassOne {
  public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class TypeClassTwo {
  public DateTime Begin {get; set;}
  public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

How can I configure AutoMapper to have a mapping like this

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
 {
    c.CreateMap<DomainClass, TypeClassOne>()
    .??? <= I would like OnlyIf(source => source.Type == 1)
 }
```

I've tried ForMember, but it doesn't works at class level...
Anyone tried to do this ?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you'd ever need to do this as you would always know the intended source and destination objects at design time. You can conditionally map properties of an object but not entire maps as far as I know. Feel free to enlighten me!

Comment: Because my domain object contains both notion of what it's store in database. It's a kind of aggregate of multiple table, and based on a filter, I have to fill one table or another. I've tried to express the simplest example I could have. In fact, in my case, we can have a collection of DomainClass and I have to store them in differents table depending of some conditions

Comment: So create mapping configurations for both cases and conditionally choose which one to use in your business logic.

Comment: It would be simple if I have control, however, this DomainClass is nested within another mapped object, I don't know how to nest mapping like this with configuration ...

Comment: You should edit your question to represent the actual problem you're facing. As it stands, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: In fact, I will simply ignore them on my top level class, and do mapping by hands when adapting from Domain to Persistence classes